# LG Ultrafine 4K display not detected on Lenovo Thinkbook

Tags: lenovo, external-monitor, lg

I’m running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a [Lenovo ThinkBook 13s G2](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkBook/ThinkBook_13s_G2_ITL/ThinkBook_13s_G2_ITL_Spec.PDF), and I’m having trouble connecting to my [LG Ultrafine 4K](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-22MD4KA-B-4k-uhd-led-monitor) monitor.

The monitor was originally designed to work with MacBooks, but while searching about this issue I’ve found plenty of folks who successfully got it to work with Ubuntu [on Lenovos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393993/lg-ultrafine-24md4kl-b-not-charging-via-usb-c-thunderbolt), although with some other small issues (see related questions). The display is quite unusual, as it only has thunderbolt usb-c input and no buttons to physically turn it on, as it automatically turns on when connected.

When connecting the display through the thunderbolt enabled cable, nothing shows up, but the laptop screen starts cycling between on and off, while nothing happens on the external monitor.

I’ve checked the Ubuntu settings and thunderbolt capability is correctly detected and enabled, it is also enabled in the BIOS settings.

Is there anything I could do to solve the issue or even diagnose what the problem is? As right now, with nothing being detected, I can’t even run `lspci` to get some more insights.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!! :)

Edit:

- I tried a different display manager (lightdm) but the behavior remained the same
- I was finally able to detect something: by running `sudo dmesg -w` when connecting the display I can see it's failing to connect to the monitor in a loop, below is an extract of the log.

```
[ 2249.592119] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=043e, idProduct=9a61, bcdDevice=52.49
[ 2249.592129] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2249.592133] usb 3-3: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[ 2249.592136] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: LG Electronics Inc.
[ 2249.595526] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 2249.598476] hub 3-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 2249.909377] usb 3-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 82 using xhci_hcd
[ 2249.968589] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 81
[ 2250.013417] usb 3-3.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2250.221353] usb 3-3.4: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2250.429375] usb 3-3.4: device not accepting address 82, error -71
[ 2250.429589] usb 3-3-port4: attempt power cycle
[ 2251.089276] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 86 using xhci_hcd
[ 2251.217345] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2251.476312] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=043e, idProduct=9a61, bcdDevice=52.49
[ 2251.476322] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2251.476326] usb 3-3: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[ 2251.476329] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: LG Electronics Inc.
[ 2251.481378] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 2251.481751] hub 3-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 2251.793406] usb 3-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 87 using xhci_hcd
[ 2251.816316] usb 3-3-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 2251.816364] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 86
[ 2251.816509] usb 3-3-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 2251.816707] usb 3-3-port4: attempt power cycle
[ 2252.793403] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 91 using xhci_hcd
[ 2252.921434] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71

...

[ 2189.262909] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=043e, idProduct=9a61, bcdDevice=52.49
[ 2189.262921] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2189.262925] usb 3-3: Product: USB2.1 Hub
[ 2189.262928] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: LG Electronics Inc.
[ 2189.265375] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 2189.268010] hub 3-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 2189.550110] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 43
[ 2189.580306] usb 3-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[ 2189.580961] usb 3-3-port4: attempt power cycle
[ 2190.560356] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
[ 2190.597036] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 2190.597045] thunderbolt 0000:00:0d.3: interrupt for RX ring 0 is already disabled
[ 2190.597123] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 18366 at drivers/thunderbolt/nhi.c:137 ring_interrupt_active+0x269/0x310 [thunderbolt]
 ...
```